# Bug in std::variant implementation of gcc7

Tags: c++, gcc, constexpr, variant, c++17

Consider [this](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%0Aconstexpr+auto+cc+%3D+!'c!'%3B%0Aconstexpr+std::variant%3Cconst+int*,const+char*%3E+pp%7B%26cc%7D%3B%0Aconstexpr+std::variant%3Cconst+int%26,const+char%26%3E+rr%7Bcc%7D%3B++//+FAILS+%3F!!'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z+-O3'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) code:

```
#include <variant>

constexpr auto cc = 'c';
constexpr std::variant<const int*,const char*> pp{&cc}; // passes
constexpr std::variant<const int&,const char&> rr{cc};  // FAILS ?!
```

With `g++ (GCC) 7.0.0 20161023 (experimental)` the last line fails with error message:

```
variant|199 col 9| error: call to non-constexpr function ‘void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)’          
||        { ::new (&_M_storage) _Type(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

pointing to constructor:

```
template<typename... _Args>
constexpr _Uninitialized(in_place_index_t<0>, _Args&&... __args)
: _M_storage{} // This was added manually
{ ::new (&_M_storage) _Type(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Actually, before this there were two more issues:

First it was complaining `call to non-constexpr function ‘std::_Enable_default_constructor<false, _Tag>::_Enable_default_constructor(std::_Enable_default_constructor_tag)` I've fixed it by making `constexpr` the constructor `_Enable_default_constructor<false, _Tag>::_Enable_default_constructor(_Enable_default_constructor_tag) { }`

Then it was complaining `_M_storage’ must be initialized by mem-initializer in ‘constexpr’ constuctor` I've fixed it by adding `: _M_storage{}` to the member initialization list, though I don't think it should complain as the added line should be generated implicitly.

So the first question is: this is certainly a bug right?

And the second question is: how can I workaround it by changing the library codes before gcc will fix it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70029) is related to your problem.

Comment: Submit a bug report.

Comment: @Barry where? how?

Comment: Heh, the standard draft is hilariously broken on this point: "If Tj's selected constructor is a constexpr constructor, this constructor shall be a constexpr constructor." References and scalars have no constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's "fixed" in the standard by disallowing references as variant alternatives (for now). GCC 7.0.1's snapshot from 2017-03-29 seems to do that correctly.